# Restore nandroid backup on an other phone

Tags: adb, backup, stock-android, nandroid

I have a nandroid backup of a huawey y600 and I have to restore it in an other huawei y600.Can I do that?If I do that the imei will change on the phone in wich I do the restore?

Comment: When you restore, you can choose what you want to restore. Do not restore / EFS and you are safe

Comment: I have not this option.I am with carliv touch recovery

Comment: Which version of TWRP? Can you look the source of TWRP in the quotation?

Answer (score 0):

The guy in this site did this. It might work if you have TWRP because he did this

1. Made a quick backup to generate the proper folder structure and the correct directory name needed for my new phone.
2. Copied the folder that contained the backup I intended to use from my old Hercules S2 to my replacement Hercules S2's TWRP backup directory.
   3.Copied the name of the folder of the backup I made in step 1 to the clipboard.
3. deleted the folder I created in step 1.
4. renamed the folder I imported by pasting the name from the clipboard.
5. restored the backup.
   Done.

The link to the chat discussion http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1949020.

Comment: I have not understood.Can I do this thing or not?I will copy my backup on my sd card and then I will restore that backup frome the same recovery to the other phone.I want to do this.What I don't know is if the nandroid backup contains   the backup of the imei or other univocal information of the phone that could give problems to the phone when the backup will be restored.

Comment: I do not think that I has a copy of the IMEI and yes it could probably be done.